# TcpListener implementation for windows phone 7

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm looking a TcpListener implementation in c# because I'm doing a server ftp for wp7/wp8 and I found a ready to user lib, but use TcpListener, that in wp7 is not present, can you find a solution?

thanks

Comment: Did you see the sockets sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Tic-Tac-Toe-Over-Sockets-cffbffd3 ?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Did you see the `listener` requirement and the explanation of the sample that you linked? `"... with the phone as the client ..."`

Comment: @jgauffin If the server was running on the phone, that seems "dangerous" at best, as the IP address may change at the drop of a hat (or be firewalled beyond all comprehension by the network). The sample illustrates how to use "custom" protocols in an client capacity, which may be a better overall architecture; and might be more appropriate than a [thin metal ruler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/03/a-parable.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: @RowlandShaw: You know nothing about the OPs requirements or when/where the phone is going to act as an server. It's fully possible to run the phone as a server without being dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to listen for incoming connections in Windows Phone 7.1. The [Silverlight Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) used in that system doesn't provide that functionality. There is no way to implement a server in WP 7.1.

That possibility was addes for the first time in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: [Connecting with sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh452976.aspx). You may want to use [StreamSocketListener class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener.aspx)